# Do the equivalent of document.getElementsByClassName() with cheerio and a url for web scraping

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, url, cheerio

[image]

this is working in the browser but when im trying to do the same thing with cheerio and node.js its not working :

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var url = 'https://www.google.fr/search?ei=apX6WdzaIMzWUabjqvAF&q=ok&oq=ok&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1l4j0j0i67k1l2j0i131k1j0j0i67k1.2633.3962.0.4021.3.3.0.0.0.0.58.169.3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.169....0.524Rrv-4zlU'

request(url, function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    console.log($('.r')[0].innerText);
  }
});
```

i have never used cheerio, and this code give me undefined message in terminal, why ?

Comment: Why not use `$('.r').text()`?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the value of `html` is the expected one?

Comment: when i use .text(), that says me : $(...)[0].text is not a function

Comment: and yes the value of html is the expected one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [cheerio doc](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#first), it looks like you could use:

```
$('.r').first().text()
```

or

```
$('.r').eq(0).text()
```

I don't know if cheerio supports direct array access like jQuery does and since these aren't real DOM objects (but are pseudo objects created by Cheerio), I don't see any support for `.innerText` in the Cheerio doc and, in fact, a Github search for "innerText" does not get any hits either.  It looks like you can use `.html()` or `.text()` on a Cheerio collection object.

If you get a specific node object like you may have been trying to do with `$('.r')[0]`, then the properties supported on that node object (which is different than a cheerio collection object) [are listed here](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#the-dom-node-object) and as follows:

```
tagName
parentNode
previousSibling
nextSibling
nodeValue
firstChild
childNodes
lastChild
```

So, if you get the actual node object, you could probably use:

```
$('.r').get(0).nodeValue
```

And, that would get you the raw contents of the node.  I expect that the earlier `.text()` examples are probably a safer and easier way to get your result.